# pandas how to get values from df2 for df1 while df1 and df2 have values overlapped on column(s)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two `df`s, the `df1` looks like,

```
df1
id
1
2
3
4
5

df2
doc_no    c_id
2         22
3         33
4         44
6         66
7         77
```

values of `id` in `df1` overlaps some values of `doc_no` in `df2`; I want to get `c_id` for `df1` from `df2` for overlapped `doc_no`, so the result looks like,

```
df1
id    c_id
1     NaN 
2     22
3     33
4     44
5     NaN
```

apart from using `df1` lefts join `df2` on `id` and `doc_no`, I am wondering if there is other better way to do this, which is more concise and efficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.map()`

```
>>> df2 = pd.DataFrame({'doc_no':[2,3,4,6,7], 'c_id':[22,33,44,66,77]})
>>> df1 = pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3,4,5]})

>>> df1
   id
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4
4   5

>>> df2
   doc_no  c_id
0       2    22
1       3    33
2       4    44
3       6    66
4       7    77

>>> df2_dict = dict(zip(df2['doc_no'], df2['c_id']))
>>> df1['c_id'] = df1['id'].map(df2_dict)

>>> df1
   id  c_id
0   1   NaN
1   2  22.0
2   3  33.0
3   4  44.0
4   5   NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `df1.merge(df2)` (which is basically a left/right/inner join more described). Anyway, are you having any performance problem on your program due to the left join? This should be done quick.

Regards!